# Why Xcode C compiler does not display properly some of the ASCII table characters?

Tags: c, xcode, gcc, compiler-construction

I'm developing a program in C using Xcode.To be practical let's take the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {

    printf("%c",3);

}
```

It's supposed to display the hearts character but it doesn't,instead just a interrogation icon show's up!And,at least for me,this is happening for many other 'special' characters.Anyone knows the reason of this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ASCII character 3 is a control character called "end of text." It does not stand for a hearts symbols. You may think that it does because the PC console generated a heart-suit symbol when a program tried to print that character. There's no reason why a modern system should follow the same convention, although the console emulator of Windows `cmd.exe` might still do it.

If you want to output a heart-suit symbol in a modern environment you should use Unicode, for example:

```
printf("%s", "\u2665");
```